# Drawing Farseer Fixtures

Tags: xna, c#, rendering, farseer-physics-engine

Is there any way how to draw a `Polygon` / `Fixture` from Farseer Physics with XNA?
As I deform these polygons at runtime I can't take any texture from my Content folder, the texture must be generated at runtime too.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw the polygons easily, if you attach the [DebugView](http://alexgamedev.blogspot.ca/2012/03/physis-engine-tutorialbasic2-debugview.html) from farseer, in your physics simulation.

If this is not what you want, you will need to write your own renderer, which is not going to be a trivial task.

You could also extend the DebugView from the Farseer library, seeing as it is open source.